# CGAL program compilation error using Eigen3

Tags: c++, matrix, compiler-errors, eigen, cgal

I want to use CGAL wrapper for OpenGR to register two point clouds(reference.ply and 1.ply), and I wrote the following simple program (basically copying from the CGAL OpenGR example):

```
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/read_ply_points.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/write_ply_points.h>
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <CGAL/Aff_transformation_3.h>

#include <CGAL/OpenGR/compute_registration_transformation.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef K::Vector_3 Vector_3;
typedef std::pair<Point_3, Vector_3> Pwn;
typedef CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<Pwn> Point_map;
typedef CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<Pwn> Normal_map;

namespace params = CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    const char* fname1 = "data/reference.ply";
    const char* fname2 = "data/1.ply";
    std::vector<Pwn> pwns1, pwns2;
    std::ifstream input(fname1);
    if (!input ||
        !CGAL::read_ply_points(input, std::back_inserter(pwns1),
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<Pwn>()).
            normal_map(Normal_map())))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file " << fname1 << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    input.close();
    input.open(fname2);
    if (!input ||
        !CGAL::read_ply_points(input, std::back_inserter(pwns2),
            CGAL::parameters::point_map(Point_map()).
            normal_map(Normal_map())))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file " << fname2 << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    input.close();

    std::cerr << "Computing registration transformation using OpenGR Super4PCS.." << std::endl;
    // First, compute registration transformation using OpenGR Super4PCS                                                                
    K::Aff_transformation_3 res =
        std::get<0>( // get first of pair, which is the transformation                                                                  
            CGAL::OpenGR::compute_registration_transformation
            (pwns1, pwns2,
                params::point_map(Point_map()).normal_map(Normal_map()),
                params::point_map(Point_map()).normal_map(Normal_map()))
            );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error occurs when I compile the program using Makefile created by cmake, and there are a lot of errors that involves the Eigen library (The error is pretty long):

```
senyangjiang@senyangjiang-MS-7A38:~/Desktop/dev_compare/cgal_compare/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target compare
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compare.dir/compare.cpp.o
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:29:127: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<float, double, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<float, double> >’
   29 |   typedef typename ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename traits<LhsCleaned>::Scalar, typename traits<RhsCleaned>::Scalar>::ReturnType Scalar;
      |                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~
home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:83:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::coeff’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   83 |     using Base::coeff;
      |                 ^~~~~
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:84:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::coeffByOuterInner’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   84 |     using Base::coeffByOuterInner;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:85:26: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::operator()’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   85 |     using Base::operator();
      |                          ^
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:86:26: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::operator[]’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   86 |     using Base::operator[];
      |                          ^
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:87:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::x’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   87 |     using Base::x;
      |                 ^
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:88:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::y’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   88 |     using Base::y;
      |                 ^
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:89:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::z’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   89 |     using Base::z;
      |                 ^
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:90:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>}::w’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0> >::Base’ {aka ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, Eigen::Homogeneous<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, 0>, 0>, 0>’}
   90 |     using Base::w;
      |                 ^
... more errors like this
/home/senyangjiang/Desktop/dev_compare/OpenGR/3rdparty/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:834:3: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
  834 |   EIGEN_CHECK_BINARY_COMPATIBILIY(Func,typename ActualDstTypeCleaned::Scalar,typename Src::Scalar);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compare.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/compare.dir/compare.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/compare.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I can solve the error by changing my code from

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
```

to

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<float> K;
```

in other words, changing double to float. But I prefer using double due to higher precision, is there any other way to resolve the error?

Comment: That is weird. What are the versions of Eigen and of OpenGR that you use?

Comment: I just downloaded these libraries yesterday. I am following the compilation guide from OpenGR website: https://storm-irit.github.io/OpenGR/a00002.html. The Eigen library comes with OpenGR when I cloned the repository. Cmake tells me that Eigen is of version 3.3.90